# Zend Framework 2 project crashing on heroku

Tags: php, heroku, zend-framework2, composer-php

I have used this [tutorial](http://www.jayhaabee.nl/blog/2013/02/php-zend-framework-2-and-composer-on-heroku/) as my guideline for setting up a zf2 project on heroku. The app deploys on heroku but the dyno crashes suddenly after that and does not load the project.

From the logs, I can see that it is unable to open web-boot.sh file in heroku folder in the root directory.

Following is my log trace

```
2014-08-18T06:10:39.793559+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `sh www/heroku/web-boot.sh`
2014-08-18T06:10:40.635178+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: Can't open www/heroku/web-boot.sh
2014-08-18T06:10:41.380597+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-08-18T06:10:41.380597+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-08-18T06:10:41.368316+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 2
2014-08-18T06:10:48.431308+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: Can't open www/heroku/web-boot.sh
2014-08-18T06:10:47.975671+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `sh www/heroku/web-boot.sh`
2014-08-18T06:10:49.122386+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 2
2014-08-18T06:10:49.133922+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-08-18T06:10:50.371350+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=helpost.herokuapp.com request_id=3e957942-3456-4513-a713-ea99d0154926 fwd="54.81.202.247" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-08-18T06:20:16.319906+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=helpost.herokuapp.com request_id=e7a0f7c3-1e15-4ad1-a327-c7f95fb79421 fwd="171.78.32.46" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-08-18T06:20:18.297172+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=helpost.herokuapp.com request_id=64877d05-01c4-4fbc-b1dc-ab91e1f8aa21 fwd="171.78.32.46" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Anyone who can help me on this? It is really important for me to get this done!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any of those instructions anymore. The information is old and outdated; Heroku now has official support for PHP including Composer.

Change the `Procfile` entry:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/
```

That should be all you need. You can drop the `heroku/` directory too.

Please read the docs: https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/php